# REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract desired string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a string format of `HISTORY-VDF-DE-EOF-WORK VDF-DE-EOF-WORK FFOR-1!20170904T105949.630 GMT` in a column.

Need to extract `FFOR-*` from it.
where `FFOR-*` is ascending order and `20170904T105949.630` is date format and timestamp which changes for every entry in column.

Have tried

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('source column', '\d[FFOR-]*') as order FROM table;
```

but no luck.

How can I extract it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ Egor Skriptunoff, could you please check

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. `REGEXP_SUBSTR('source column', 'FFOR-.*')` should work (according what you have written)

Comment: Thanks @ Wernfried, I have one table called PC_HISTORY_WORK , where in PZINSKEY column value pattern is like "HISTORY-VDF-DE-EOF-WORK VDF-DE-EOF-WORK FFOR-1!20170904T105949.630 GMT" , i need to extract only FFOR-*[where * is any numeric value from 1 to n]

Comment: Please give an example! What **exactly** do you expect from string `HISTORY-VDF-DE-EOF-WORK VDF-DE-EOF-WORK FFOR-1!20170904T105949.630 GMT` as result? A second or third example would also help.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit
This are few entries for example, 

HISTORY-VDF-DE-EOF-WORK VDF-DE-EOF-WORK FFOR-21!20171012T050703.604 GMT
HISTORY-VDF-DE-EOF-WORK VDF-DE-EOF-WORK FFOR-126!20171213T090324.784 GMT

now from all this kind of values from i want to extract only FFOR-1, FFOR-21 and FFOR-126

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting it into comment. Anyway, in this case solution from Littlefoot `regexp_substr(col, 'FFOR-\d+')` is working.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a regular expression solution? Because, an *ordinary* SUBSTR with INSTR does the job as well:

[EDITED, after seeing what output is required]

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select 'HISTORY-VDF-DE-EOF-WORK VDF-DE-EOF-WORK FFOR-1!20170904T105949.630 GMT' col
  3     from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6    substr(col,
  7           instr(col, 'FFOR-'),
  8           instr(col, '!', -1) - instr(col, 'FFOR-')
  9          ) result
 10  from test;

RESULT
------
FFOR-1

SQL>
```

[EDIT #2, with REGEXP]

Note that, although it looks "smarter", for large data volume it *might* be slower than SUBSTR option.

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select 'HISTORY-VDF-DE-EOF-WORK VDF-DE-EOF-WORK FFOR-1!20170904T105949.630 GMT' col
  3     from dual
  4    )
  5  select regexp_substr(col, 'FFOR-\d+') result
  6  from test;

RESULT
------
FFOR-1

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but i need only FFOR-* value not the date and timestamp.
result would look like FFOR-1 that means i need to remove also !***************.*** GMT
The prob is numeric value could be 1 to n as it will ascending everyday
I also tried tried with REGXP_REPLACE but no luck

Comment: Based on your example, what string EXACTLY do you need as a result? Is it "FFOR-1!" (including minus, number one and exclamation sign), or ...? [EDIT] Aha, I see, you've edited the comment.

Comment: @S.Das, I've edited my answer's example. Would that be OK?

Comment: i must do this with REGXP, this is a very small part of a script, so i need to use somthing generic as scripts will run everyday.

Comment: That "SUBSTR" is *generic* (unless I misunderstood the question). You need only it, the rest of my example is here *just for example*, of course you wouldn't have it in your code.

Comment: @S.Das, I edited my example once again, adding REGEXP option. Any better now?

Comment: Thanks for solution now i am facing new prob if i give the column name it is taking all the results null.
let me give you actual scenario I have one table called PC_HISTORY_WORK , where in PZINSKEY column value pattern is like "HISTORY-VDF-DE-EOF-WORK VDF-DE-EOF-WORK FFOR-1!20170904T105949.630 GMT" , i need to extract only FFOR-*[where * is any numeric value from 1 to n]

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR I provided in my last example works correctly, as far as I can tell. If you disagree, please, edit your initial message and provide test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data), specify which result you expect out of every sample record and I'll have a look.